# I get URL not found I use Flask render_template method

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am writing an application which is managing forms using Flask as backend framework.

When I fill data in the form(username and password) correctly, instead of the program returning `'Form sucessfully submitted'`, I get the following error:

**Not Found**

**The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.**

Why is that happening?

Notice 1: I put a HTML file in templates directory, so that is not a cause of the error

Notice 2: I wrote here only the code which is relevant to this problem

**Here is the code:**

**1) application.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Email, Length, AnyOf
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

app = Flask(__name__)

Bootstrap(app)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'somePassword'

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('username', validators=[InputRequired(), Email(message='I don\'t like your email.')])
    password = PasswordField('password', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=5, max=10), AnyOf(['secret', 'password'])])

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return 'Form sucessfully submitted'
    return render_template('loginForm1.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**2) loginForm1.html**

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block title %}
WTForms
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <form method="POST" action="/">
        <dl>
            {{ wtf.quick_form(form)}}
            <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-info">
        </dl>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've defined the route as `/login` but your form is posting to `/`.

Comment: I checked this out now and your observation is correct.
Now it is working.